# Family of Bachmann–Landau notations

Tags: algorithm, math, computer-science

Could please help me to understand notation's that mention in the picture?, I try to understand **"Big O notation"** in that under the **"Family of Bachmann–Landau notations"** Table there is "Formal Definition" column, in that, there are lot's notation with equation, i did't come across these notation before. could any one familiar with this ?  [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann–Landau_notations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1HVnC.jpg)

Comment: What exactly confuses you about these definitions? What do you already know about Big-O? Do you know a different definition, if so which? Currently your question is broad and an adequate answer would need to explain the big topic of Big-O in a whole to cover everything you could have meant. Please only ask precise, non-broad questions (see [ask], [help]).

Comment: @Zabuza thank for your time, i have problem with understanding about those notation, (A(reverse) and E (reverse)) !

Comment: @user3764118, `∀` and `∃` are typical mathematical notations used in most of the math. `∀` is known as [Universal quantification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_quantification) and is often read as "for all" or "for every" while `∃` is [Existential quantification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Existential_quantification) which is often read as "there exists (at least one) ... such that".

Comment: @SergGr yes thank you that's i'm looking for !

Comment: @user3764118, so for example the line `∀ k > 0 ∃ n0 ∀ n > n0 |f(n)| < k*g(n)` should be read as "for every positive `k` there exist a value `n0` such that for every `n` such that `n > n0` it holds that `|f(n)| < k*g(n)`". Or in more layman's terms for every positive multiplier `k` you can go far away enough (`n0`) such that after that point (`n > n0`) the value of `|f(n)|` is less than `k*g(n)`. Or even more informally at the infinity `f(n)` is "fundamentally less than" `g(n)`

Comment: @SergGr wow thank's lot it's really clear explanation!

Comment: @user3764118, you are welcome but generally such pure Math/CS questions are better answered at other sites such as [https://math.stackexchange.com/](https://math.stackexchange.com/) or [https://cs.stackexchange.com/](https://cs.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic behind that definitions are actually quite simple, it basically says that no matter what constants are multiplying the result, from some point where `n` is big enough, the one of the function will start to being bigger/smaller and it remains that way.

To see real difference, I will explain th `small-o` (which says that some function has smaller complexity than other), it says that for all `k` bigger than zero you can find some value of `n` called `n_0` for which all `n` bigger than `n_0` follows this pattern: `f(n) <= k*g(n)`.

So you have two functions and you put there `n` as a parameter. Then no matter what you put as `k`, you always find value of `n` for which `f(n) <= k*g(n)` and all value that are bigger than the one you have find will also fit into this equation.

Consider for example:

```
f(n) = n * 100
g(n) = n^2
```

So if you try to put i.e. `n=5` there, it does not say you what has bigger complexity, because `5*100=500` and `5^2=25`. If you put number big enough, i.e. `n=100`, then `f(n)=100*100=10000` and `g(n)=100^2=100*100=10000`. So we get to the same value. If you try to put anything bigger than that, the g(n) will become bigger and bigger.

It also have to follow the equation `f(n) <= k*g(n)`. In example, if I put i.e. `k=0.1` then

```
100*n <= 0.1*n^2 *10
1000n <= n^2 /n
1000 < n
```

So with that functions, you can see that for `k=0.1` you have `n_0 = 1000` to fulfill the equations, but it is enough. All `n > 1000` will be bigger and the function `g(n)` will always be bigger, therefore it has higher complexity. (ok, the real proof is not that easy, but you can see the pattern). The point is, no matter what `k` will be, even if it is equal `k=0.000000001`, there always be breaking point of `n_0` and from that point, all `g(n)` will be bigger than `f(n)`

We can also try some negative equations to see whats difference between `O(n)` and `O(n^2)`.

Lets take:

```
f(n) = n
g(n) = 10*n
```

So in standard algebra the `g(n) > f(n)`, right? But in complexity theory we need to know if it grows bigger and if so, if it grows bigger than just multiplying it with constant.

So if we consider that `k=0.01`, then you can see that no matter how big the `n` will be, you never find `n_0` that fulfills the `f(n) <= k*g(n)`, so the `f(n) != o(g(n))`

In terms of complexity theory you can take the notations as smaller/bigger, so

```
f(n) = o(g(n)) -> f(n) < g(n)
f(n) = O(g(n)) -> f(n) <= g(n)
f(n) = Big-Theta(g(n)) -> f(n) === g(n)
//... etc, remember these euqations are not algebraic, just for complexity
```

Comment: thank you for your brief explanation, could you please suggest me where can i study more about those notations's (A(reverse),E(reverse)) ?

Comment: @user3764118 - not sure what this `(A(reverse),E(reverse))` means :)

Comment: notation or letter, which the used in that equation (in 1st equation `v*k>0` and `E(reverse)*n0`)

Comment: @user3764118 - sorry, not really sure what you are talking about :)

Comment: He is talking about the mathematical quantifiers `∀` and `∃`. So basic math which can be studied on the internet or in any math course that is beyond school level (like university).

Comment: @user3764118 - ahh, now I understand, sorry, I was just looking for some special reverse equations :D. `A(reverse)` is "for all", the `E(reverse)` is exists

Comment: @user3764118 - really not sure where to study that, we learned that in high school

Comment: @user3764118 Typically the first thing students learn in the first lecture of any math-related course. Quantifiers and other logic tools like `A => B`, `A <= B` and `A <=> B`, `not A`, `A and B`, `A or B`. You can read more about it on [Wikipedia#First-order logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic).

Comment: @Zabuza ya it's bit difficult to ask this kind of question because i never seen such or maybe i avoided, but any way you guys helped me, thank you all !

Comment: @user3764118 [math.se] may be more appropriate for those kind of questions though.